# How to make it possible to change the width of the stripes?

Tags: unity, shaders, shaderlab

I am making a shader to create stripes based on [this tutorial](https://andreashackel.de/tech-art/stripes-shader-1/), but I cannot set the width for each stripe and make a shader that accepts light.

```
Shader "Unlit/Stripes-2"
{
    Properties{
        [IntRange] _NumColors("Number of colors", Range(2, 4)) = 2
        _Color1("Color 1", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _Ratio1("Width 1", Float) = 0.1 // Width for first color.
        _Color2("Color 2", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Ratio2("Width 2", Float) = 0.1
        _Color3("Color 3", Color) = (1,0,1,1)
        _Ratio3("Width 3", Float) = 0.1
        _Color4("Color 4", Color) = (0,0,1,1)
        _Ratio4("Width 4", Float) = 0.1
        _Tiling("Tiling", Range(1, 500)) = 10
        _WidthShift("Width Shift", Range(-1, 1)) = 0
        _Direction("Direction", Range(0, 1)) = 0
        _WarpScale("Warp Scale", Range(0, 1)) = 0
        _WarpTiling("Warp Tiling", Range(1, 10)) = 1
    }

        SubShader
    {

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            int _NumColors;
            fixed4 _Color1;
            fixed4 _Color2;
            fixed4 _Color3;
            fixed4 _Color4;
            int _Tiling;
            float _WidthShift;
            float _Direction;
            float _WarpScale;
            float _WarpTiling;

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            float2 rotatePoint(float2 pt, float2 center, float angle) {
                float sinAngle = sin(angle);
                float cosAngle = cos(angle);
                pt -= center;
                float2 r;
                r.x = pt.x * cosAngle - pt.y * sinAngle;
                r.y = pt.x * sinAngle + pt.y * cosAngle;
                r += center;
                return r;
            }

            float random(float2 uv)
            {
                return frac(sin(dot(uv, float2 (12.9898, 78.233))) * 43758.5453123);
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                const float PI = 3.14159;

                float2 pos = rotatePoint(i.uv.xy, float2(0.5, 0.5), _Direction * 2 * PI);

                pos.x += sin(pos.y * _WarpTiling * PI * 2) * _WarpScale;
                //pos.x *= _Tiling;

                int value = floor((frac(pos.x)) * _NumColors + _WidthShift);
                value = clamp(value, 0, _NumColors - 1);
                switch (value) {
                    case 3: return _Color4;
                    case 2: return _Color3;
                    case 1: return _Color2;
                    default: return _Color1;
                }
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For accepting light, presumably you considered starting with a Surface Shader instead of an Unlit Shader?

Comment: @DMGregory, Yes, I thought about it, but I don't know where to start